# Как передать куки в следующий запрос Python requests

Tags: python, cookie, requests

Как передать куки в следующий запрос, идея в том чтобы следующий запрос был уже авторизированый, то есть первым я куку получаю а вторым уже использую (Если вообще так делается)

```
 payload = {'email': '*****', 'password': '*******'}
 url = "https://first_link/"
 a = requests.Session()
 a.post(url, data=payload)
 cook = a.cookies
 print(cook)
 url2 = "second_link_only_autorized_user"
 result = a.get(url2, cookies=cook)
 print(result.cookies)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as session:
        payload = {'email': '*****', 'password': '*******'}
        url = "https://first_link/"

        session.post(url, data=payload)
        url2 = "second_link_only_autorized_user"
        result = session.get(url2)
```

> Если нужно предметней, нужен живой url

Comment: Спасибо ! Работает)
Моя ошибка еще была в том, что урл для куки нужно было брать из хедера пост запроса на авторизацию, а не обычный урл :)